# MAUI ListView gets app to crash/is buggy on Android when scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, maui

I am developing the prototype for a mobile application in MAUI, just for Android right now. The `ListView` is not working as expected for me though. Everything is fine when the number of items fit the screen, but the moment there is scrolling involved, the app crashes. The underlying Android error seems to be:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.
```

If I scroll *very* slowly, the issue does not seem to occur. Here's the `ListView`:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
          Style="{StaticResource ListViewSimpleStyle}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell x:DataType="local:DeviceEntryModel">
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      GroupName="Devices">
          <RadioButton.Content>
              <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=BindingContext}"
                      Text="{Binding Name}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsEnabled}" />
          </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The item source is an `ObservableCollection<DeviceEntry>`:

```cs
public partial class DeviceEntryModel : ObservableObject
{
  public DeviceEntry DeviceEntry { get; init; }

  public string Name { get => DeviceEntry.Name; }

  public string Address { get => DeviceEntry.Address; }

  [ObservableProperty]
  bool isChecked;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

One thing I have tried that does fix the crashing is to set the `ListView` `CachingStrategy` to `"RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"`. The problem with that is, if a radio button is checked and goes out of view while scrolling, it loses its state and becomes unchecked. There are also various other bugs, like the list item text disappearing.

Comment: If this issue is persistent and you can recreate it in a sample repository, then you may want to file a bug in the MAUI repository: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues But first check if this issue was reported already

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all the issues, wrap the whole `ListView` XAML in a `ScrollView`.

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
            Style="{StaticResource ListViewSimpleStyle}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell x:DataType="local:DeviceEntryModel">
                  <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              GroupName="Devices">
                      <RadioButton.Content>
                          <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsEnabled}" />
                      </RadioButton.Content>
                  </RadioButton>
              </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Does it work if instead of `<ScrollView>`, you use `<StackLayout>`? If so, I recommend that. ListView already has scrolling logic; wrapping in ScrollView could potentially cause bugs in some circumstances, on some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

@something5143

I don't known the solution but on the [.NET MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0)

> Warning
>
> ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition, ScrollView
> objects should not be nested with other controls that provide
> scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView.